# Ember.js bound Image with size flickering in Chrome

Tags: image, binding, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple handlebars template where I have some number of items and I bind image `src` attribute form each item to logoUrl property, something like:

```
{{#each App.stationsController}}
  <img height="50" width="50" {{bindAttr src="logoUrl"}} {{bindAttr alt="name"}}/>
  {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

and it I have some code changing array in `stationController`.
Sometimes (not always but often) I see for a glimpse gray border around image square somehting like a gray border Chrome shows for broken images.
Removing image sizes stops this effect but it's not always a good option.
I use Chrome 18.0.1025.168 on Ubuntu Natty.
With Chromium I don't see flickering.
Any hints on what could be going on and how this effect could be stopped (without removing image size)?

**Update**

I've created example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Va8C2/3/

And screenshot showing described border may be seen at http://imgur.com/diPct it's a frame 67 from mpeg file http://www.sendspace.com/file/my0gv4

*Imgur returns 403 on first 'indirect' image load opening station images in other browser tab helps to solve it*

**Update2**

Looks like the root of the problem was found but disabling AdBlock isn't a good solution.

Comment: You're binding the src attribute 2 times. I guess this is not intended. Can you provide a JSFiddle which demonstrates your problem. What "changes" are made in your `stationController`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that Adblock extention slows Chrome rendering process.

Comment: Yep, looks like it does. Disabling AdBlock for particular site does not solve the problem only disbaling plugin grobally helps